# How do I keep floated child divs from wrapping?

Tags: html, css, css-float, z-index

I'm trying to make a carousel type control that allows a user to pick radio button that's within one of many div elements. The idea is to have 20 or so 150px divs that contain radio buttons. I don't want those 20 divs to wrap once they reach the right side of the container. I tried setting the container overflow to hidden but that didn't work. The basic html layout is

```
<div class="scheduler">
  <div class="scheduler-inner">
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        ...<div class="item">...</div>
  </div>
  <a class="scheduler">...</a>
  <a class="scheduler">...</a>
</div>
```

I'm really just looking for some CSS guidance. I don't want to have a scroll bar on `.scheduler-inner`  and I will use javascript to move the `.item` left or right on the click of the anchors. How should `.scheduler-inner` be styled? I have

```
.scheduler-inner { overflow:hidden; }
.scheduler-inner > div { float:left; width:10em; }
```

but they wrap as soon as it hits the edge of `.scheduler-inner`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need isn't floating but the style `white-space: nowrap;`

Apply the nowrap on your container and set your items to display inline. Refer to the jsfiddle below.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/of5dmjux/

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you. No on to the animation piece. =)